# How do i save a list to a htb file?

Tags: python, save

I am trying to create one lagre htb file out of many small htb files. It works so far that i can create a list with the content of all files in the directory. How can i save my list to a htb file again?
Can any of you help me? Heres my code so far:

```
import os

folderpath = r"C:/Users/l-reh/Desktop/HTB" 
filepaths  = [os.path.join("C:/Users/l-reh/Desktop/HTB/", name) for name in os.listdir(folderpath)]
all_files = []

for path in filepaths:
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        file = f.readlines()
        all_files.append(file)
```

Comment: then i get this error: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found

Answer (score 0):

You can join a nested list of lists using [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> all_files = [["this is some", "content"], ["this", "is more stuff"], ["and", "more and", "more"]]
>>> newfile_contents = "\n".join(chain.from_iterable(all_files))
>>> print(newfile_contents)
this is some
content
this
is more stuff
and
more and
more
```